# Joomla 3 template plugin is not working

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I am new to Joomla plugin development and I am trying to build a basic Hello World plugin.

What I want is for the text "Hello World" to appear in the front-end after the article title.
I am running Joomla 3.3.6.
The following is my code base:
/helloworld/

- **helloworld.xml**

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <extension version="3.3" type="plugin" group="content" method="upgrade">
            <name>plg_content_helloworld</name>
            <author>Test Author</author>
            <creationDate>04/02/2015</creationDate>
            <copyright>None</copyright>
            <license>GNU General Public License</license>
            <authorEmail>me@memail.com</authorEmail>
            <authorUrl>http://www.example.com</authorUrl>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <description>Simple Hello World Plugin that prints "Hello World" at the beginning of every article.</description>
            <files>
                    <filename plugin="helloworld">helloworld.php</filename>
                    <filename>index.html</filename>
            </files>
    </extension>
```

- **helloworld.php**

```html
    <?php
    
    // no direct access
    defined('_JEXEC') or die;
    
    class plgContentHelloworld extends JPlugin
    {
        public function onContentAfterTitle($context, &$article, &$params, $limitstart)
            {
                            return "<p>Hello World!</p>";
            }
    }
    
    ?>
```

- **Empty index.html**

I have set the "Show Intro Text" value on the article to all possible values and it still does not work. I am also struggling to find any decent resources online for Joomla Plugin creation. Does anyone know of any?

Comment: Please try asking on [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Did you even try and google? https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla

Comment: Yes I did, lets try keep the answers helpful thanks :) That tutorial is what I followed initially but does not work for my situation.